# How to generate the same color styles not multiple times in angular?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

In Angular, I generate a custom theme file, a root styles file, and all my components have their own custom styles file. However, since I updated to Version 10, my terminal is spammed by the warning

```
WARNING: The same color styles are generated multiple times. Read more about how style duplication can be avoided in a dedicated guide. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/duplicate-theming-styles.md
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 1648:7  -mat-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 7010:3  angular-material-theme()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 7061:3  angular-material-color()
    src/_custom_theme.scss 242:3                         @import
    stdin 2:9
```

Following the guide, I could reduce this error to a minimum of four arrivals. This error lists my custom_theme file and @angular/material from my node_modules.
I really wonder what I'm doing wrong leading to this error. At line 242 of my custom_theme I am generating my dark theme `.custom-dark-theme { @include angular-material-color($app-theme-dark); }`

Comment: did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Actually yes. Im gonna post it on monday.

Comment: please don't forget.. I really need it.. thank you!

Comment: where is the solution?

Comment: @MojioMS can you please share it with us?

Comment: I also need the solution.

Comment: Wheres the solution

Comment: I did not specify which monday.

Answer (score 3):

The general thing to do is to avoid your components sccs `@import`-ing a file which itself `@include`s one of the material core mixins. So you could define the theme and maybe some sharable theme constants/mixins in a partial, then create the styles in the global style which imports the theme definition. More explicitly:

- Create a file something like `_my-theme.scss`, the leading underscore makes it a sass partial.
- In this file, only *define* the theme by calling material’s `material-light-theme` *function*. Note that this is just a function, which is just creating a big Sass map that the rest of the material library uses to actually generate styles. Itself it does not “generate” styles, like the mixins do.
- In the global/root style file, import `'my-theme'`, and then `@include` The color/styles mixin.
- In your component files, only import from my custom theme partial and not from the root file

However, with the more recent versions of Sass and Angular 12, the better way to do this is instead of using `@import`, you use the `@use` syntax which better handles “sharing” common code in those partial files. Simple example/starter-code

`_my-theme.scss`

```
@use "~@angular/material" as mat;

$my-theme-dark: mat.define-dark-theme(
  // stuff here
);
```

Root `styles.scss`

```
@use "~@angular/material" as mat;
@use './my-theme' as my-theme;

@include mat.core()

// general style defaults

.app-dark {
  @include mat.all-component-colors(my-theme.$my-theme-dark);
}
```

`some-component.scss`

```
@use "~@angular/material" as mat;
@use 'my-theme' as my-theme;

// do anything with mat and your definitions from my-theme
```

Comment: Thank you - this helped me a lot. I am using Angular 13 (and Angular Material) and the most important take away here is: keep the file separation as suggested here! Create a separate, "innocent", theme SCSS, which you can then import into your custom components if need be without much hassle, and create the actual themes (one or several `@include mat.all-component-themes(...)`) inside your `styles.scss` (top most styling file). This way these methods will not be called multiple times, not resulting in multiple same color styles.

Comment: Yep - basically! You essentially want to avoid component scss `@import`-ing a file which itself `@include`'s material all-component-themes and whatnot. Happy to help